# "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" In my activity tab

Tags: bug, profile-page, error-message

I'm getting what seems to be a timeout error in random activity tabs across SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/754119/alon-eitan?tab=activity
https://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene?tab=activity
https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen?tab=activity
https://stackoverflow.com/users/4370109/brian-tompsett-%e6%b1%a4%e8%8e%b1%e6%81%a9?tab=activity
https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif?tab=topactivity

It sometimes loads but most of the time I see this error:

[image]

Comment: Confirmed. I can still repro. I'm at rev 2021.1.20.38359 based on what the footer shows.

Comment: I tried a few times, all 5 of those links work for me. Maybe it's an issue only for those in a particular location? (I tried connecting from both Canada and the US)

Comment: The last link now works just fine but the others don't. Strange

Comment: @CertainPerformance in that case I'm in western-europe.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I also get that error on your activity tab https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance?tab=topactivity

Comment: Not been able to repro in any circumstance (connecting from UK)

Comment: Reproed for 2 links.

Comment: Same here. Probably our comment count is killing SQL Server again.

Comment: I repro from the US. Some links work, but some don't. All are very slow.